# System of ODEs on a graph

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graph-theory, jacobian, directed-graphs

I have a directed graph consisting of nodes and edges. A system of ordinary differential equations describes how the value at each node changes with respect to time, as a function of the value of the surrounding nodes that are connected by edges.

After numerical integration I can see how the value at each node changes as a function of time. Is there a way for me to see how each edge affects the change at a single node (using the Jacobian perhaps)?

[Example of graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fgqc.png)

In this example, if we pick node A, I want to know the relative contributions of each of those vertices (flow coming from nodes B, C and D) at each moment in time.

Comment: What do you mean "how each edge affects the change at a single node"?  Each edge adjacent to the node or each edge in the graph? And how are the edges active above indicating connectedness? Do you want the node values as some kind of potential and the edge contributions as a flow driven by the potential differences?

Comment: The nodes could indeed be potential and the flow through the edges driven by potential differences. 

I just added an example graph. In this case, if we pick node A, I want to know the relative contributions of each of those vertices (flow coming from nodes B, C and D) at each moment in time.

In answer to your question, each edge adjacent to our specific node, not each edge in the graph. The edge indicates a functional dependence on the connecting node (eg. that there is a flow between B and A, which depends on the potential at B).

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the partial derivative of $x_i(t)$ (the value at node $i$) with respect to a constant $a_{jk}$ of the system corresponding to edge $jk$. These will satisfy
differential equations as well, since
$$ \dfrac{d}{dt} \dfrac{\partial x_i}{\partial a_{jk}} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial a_{jk}} \dfrac{d x_i}{dt} $$
You will thus end up with a larger system of differential equations involving the $x_i$ and $\partial x_i/\partial a_{jk}$, which can again be solved numerically.

Comment: Could you clarify what is the meaning of a partial derivative with respect to a constant?

Comment: "Parameter" would be a better term than "constant".